# Given $B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is invertible and $B^2+B^4+B^7 = I$, find an expression for $B^{-1}$ in terms of only $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $B \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ is invertible and $B^2+B^4+B^7=I$, find an expression for $B^{-1}$ in terms of only $B$.

I don't know where to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you don't know where to start?  What exactly are you having problem with?  Did you just copy and pasted the whole question from your PDF/etc (plus adding 2 extra sentences) and looking for answer here... Please notice this is not Chegg

Comment: @user85130 So you never had a problem where you didn't know where to start? I think this is not a good way to welcome a new user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may begin with $B^{-1}=B^{-1}I$.

Comment: Thanks for helping. So do you mean I can sub b^2+b^4+b^7 in I, then get B^-1= b+b^3+b^6.

Comment: Yes. Actually the assumption that $B$ is invertible can be removed. Recall that $B$ is invertible if there is some $A$ such that $BA=I$, and if such $A$ exists, it is the inverse of $B$. Now, since $B(B+B^3+B^6)=B^2+B^4+B^7 = I$, $B$ must be invertible and $A=B^{-1}=B+B^3+B^6$.

Comment: @user2185071 You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Since $B^2 + B^4 + B^7 = I$, we have $B(B + B^3 + B^6) = I$; thus $B^{-1} = B + B^3 + B^6$.  Note also that since $B^7 + B^4 + B^2 - I = 0$, any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$ must satisfy $\lambda^7 + \lambda^4 + \lambda^2 - 1 =0$, hence cannot be $0$; thus the hypothesis that $B$ is invertable is extraneous, given that $B$ satisfies $B^2 + B^4 + B^7 = I$.  Hope this helps.